# Redirect link page is preventing my email from sending

Tags: codeigniter, email, redirect, sendmail

I added this in email signature:
Test Website
testwebsite.com

==========

## If you click testwebsite.com, it will redirect to my website mywebsite.com

Whenever I used testwebsite.com as part of the email signature on my site, the email notification is not sending. But if I changed that to mywebsite.com, the email notification is working fine.

==========

By the way, my email notification was integrated on mywebsite.com using SendMail in CodeIgniter framework.

Could you please help me why my marketing domain testwebsite.com is preventing the email notifications from sending successfully.

PS. I just used test website URLs in the above scenario for security purposes.

======

```
function send_email_template($template, $recipient, $subject = null, $vars = null) {
$ci = & get_instance();
$ci->load->model('default/m_settings');

//get site data
$website = $ci->M_website->getWebsite();

$ci->load->library('email');
$ci->email->clear();
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$ci->email->initialize($config);


// Set default subject.
if ($subject == null) {
// Try to find a "_subject" setting for the template specified.
$subject = $ci->m_settings->get($template . '_subject');

if ($subject) {
$subject = $subject->setting_value;
} else {
$subject = '';
}
}

$template = $ci->m_settings->get($template);

$body = htmlspecialchars_decode(cs_parse_vars($template->setting_value, $vars));

$body .= $ci->m_settings->get('global_email_footer')->setting_value;

$ci->email->set_newline("\r\n");

//get admin email
$ci->load->model('admin/M_administrator');
$admin_email = $ci->m_settings->get('admin_outgoing_email')->setting_value;
$email_sender_from = ($admin_email) ? $admin_email : 'no-reply@' . strtolower(preg_replace('/\s/', '-', $website['name']));
$ci->email->from($email_sender_from, $website['name']);

// _APPLICATION_ENV_ is set in /index.php
if (_APPLICATION_ENV_ != 'PRODUCTION') {
$recipient = _EMAIL_RECEPIENT_;
}

if ($recipient == '') {
#$recipient = 'jamygallardo@gmail.com';
}

$ci->email->to($recipient);
$ci->email->subject('[' . $website["name"] . '] ' . $subject);
$ci->email->message($body);

if ($ci->email->send()) {
return TRUE;
} else {
show_error('mailer error:' . $ci->email->print_debugger());
}
return TRUE;
}
```

Thanks,
Jamaica

Comment: add your code as well

Comment: if you are using any links in your mail body...mail server may detect it as an external link...So,you may get your mail in spam or due to any security reason it will not be sent

Comment: @Kunal -- what are the possible security reasons? do you have any sources that will explain this kind of issue? I am using the redirect page for marketing purposes.